# Using Parameters and wildcards on SQL server

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server, parameters, wildcard

I'm using an online SQL service where you can write an SQL query and links this to a URL. In android you can use the url in a request to return the results in a JSON format

In order to pass a parameter to the service you have to use a colon.
like this example:

```
SELECT Password FROM Users
where Username = :name
```

you would use this query with

```
http://api.a16_sd502.studev.groept.be/getUserLogin/name
```

where you can replace the last 'name' with whatever you want.

Now i have another query where i want to search in the databas that uses wildcards.

```
SELECT name, releaseDate, rating
FROM Movies 
WHERE name LIKE '%harry%'
```

This returns:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
        "releaseDate": "2001-11-22",
        "rating": "7.5"
    },
    {
        "name": "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",
        "releaseDate": "2002-11-02",
        "rating": "7.4"
    },
    {
        "name": "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban ",
        "releaseDate": "2004-06-02",
        "rating": "7.8"
    }
]
```

This doesn't use a parameter, so i would want to replace 'harry' with ':query'. That way i can pass a parameter trough the url, like in the first example like this :

```
http://api.a16_sd502.studev.groept.be/searchQuery/query
```

However, this doesn't work, as it returns an empty JSON array. What misatke am i making? I assume it's syntax related, but I can't figure it out.

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you show us the actual Java code you used for the `LIKE` query?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. The setup of the query is handled on this webservice and in Java I only need the url to get the results from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, releaseDate, rating
FROM Movies 
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',:query,'%')
```

Comment: The first suggestion also returns an empty JSON Array. But the second one worked just fine, thanks a lot!

Comment: As a warning, this query is prone to SQL injection, and prepared statements should be used if possible.